ConcatenatingAudioSource skipping to nexts tracks when loading is interrupted(network connection)
I am using ConcatenatingAudioSource and bunch of tracks as playlist, it's working fine, but when devices disconnected from network, track will play until end of loaded part of buffer then it will start loading ,after 3-4 seconds ,player will start skipping to other tracks,it will try to skip up to 5 tracks then stops trying, I can't find anything to fix this problems, ConcatenatingAudioSource is good but this problem preventing me from using it's well-written other features. If some got solution for this please share
I have tried to change ConcatenatingAudioSource itself ,but can't find anything related to this case , I want player don't skip to other tracks even if loading is interrupted , it's somehow weird I think

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
